# Java SSL handshake error - Tomcat keystore

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I've tried to connect (send some data between) my standalone app and my other app served by Tomcat via SSL:

```
https://tomcat_server:8843/app
```

Unfortunately an error appears in my standalone app:

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:827)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.flushRequestOutputStream(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1525)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1975)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
>       at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.http.HttpClientFactory.createConnection(HttpClientFactory.java:101)
>       ... 9 more

If I define url as a http it works fine:

```
http://tomcat_server:8080/app
```

It is also not a problem of app I think. I've tried the same thing with the same app on the other Tomcat server and it works via https. The only difference between these servers is I did not create the keystore file (pfx) on that server which works. I can't of course use the same keystore, because its different domain (I access this app also via browser).
There is nothing in the Tomcat's log on the server. Maybe I did something wrong while creating the keystore.

Here's how I generated the keystore file using openssl tool with my key, certificate and intermediate cert:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt -certfile intermediate.crt
```

Here is my connector config:

```
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/path/to/keystore/certificate.pfx" keystorePass="changeit"  ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
       keystoreType="PKCS12" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Both servers have same configs so I assume it must be certificate. Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you need certificate file on app side.

Comment: @disable1992 As I wrote, same app works with second Tomcat (different keystore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the certificate in JDK security. Follow below 2 step and get done.

- Step-1 Goto Below java security directory

> /path/to/java/jdk/jre/lib/security

- Step-2 Run below command

> keytool -import  -keystore cacerts -file /path/to/your/cert.cer

Answer (score 1):

Your application must a use a truststore with the public part of the certificate that you added to the keystore specified for 8443. This can be done by using system properties:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore/truststore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=truststorepassword
```

Answer (score 0):

Run: 
`openssl s_client -connect [working_server]:[working_port]` and then do the same for the server which isn't working.  Compare the results; based on your description it is likely that there are no common certificates between them.  One of the certificates in the 'broken' server's certificate chain *must* be in your app's truststore for it to work (the logs indicate that they are not); preferably you use the root certificate, but there are business cases where you may prefer an intermediate or the leaf certificate itself.